# How to correctly define relationships in a Python SQLAlchemy class with multiple base classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to recreate my database using SQLAlchemy and Flask.

I've created all the models, but now have some problems with the relationships between the models. When inserting or updating an object Flask returns the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\Lenna\SchoolMi\api-server-v4\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\clsregistry.py", line 326, in __call__
    x = eval(self.arg, globals(), self._dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    # ext/declarative/clsregistry.py
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'
```

The error message references to the active_channel relationship in the profile class and indicates that the channel class has no id attribute. However I've already defined this attribute in the ObjectWithDefaultProps class. After inspection of the SQL file in a SQL browser, the id attribute is indeed present on the Channel entity.

My first assumption was a misconfiguration of the foreignkey, so I tried to change the foreignkey:

```
active_channel = db.relationship("Channel", foreign_keys="Channel.id")
```

instead of

```
active_channel = db.relationship("Channel", foreign_keys="channel.id")
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. The error changes to the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on
        relationship Profile.active_channel - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing
        columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression. //
        Werkzeug Debugger
```

I've looked further into the polymorphism aspects of SQLAlchemy and thought it might had something to do with the **mapperargs** but couldn't figure out the correct way of implementing this.

In my code I have the following classes:

My entities derive from multiple objects, that represent shared attributes or relationships.

```
class Profile(db.Model, ObjectWithDefaultProps, ObjectWithAvatar, ObjectWithNotificationProfile):

    __tablename__ = "profile"

    firebase_uid = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    about = db.Column(db.String)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    active_channel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("channel.id"))
    active_channel = db.relationship("Channel", foreign_keys="channel.id")
```

Channel.py

```
class Channel(db.Model, ObjectBase, ObjectWithAvatar, ObjectWithName, ProfileLinkedObject):

    __tablename__ = "channel"

    description = db.Column(db.String)
    can_add_tags = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    can_public_join = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)



from database.provider import db
from datetime import datetime
class ObjectWithDefaultProps:
    deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)



from database.provider import db
from database.extensions.object_with_color import ObjectWithColor
class ObjectWithAvatar(ObjectWithColor):
    image_url = db.Column(db.String)


from database.provider import db
class ObjectWithColor:
    color_index = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)


from database.provider import db
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class ObjectWithNotificationProfile:

    auto_follow_questions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto_follow_answers = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto_follow_comments = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto_follow_questions_on_comment = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto_follow_questions_on_answer = db.Column(db.Integer)
    auto_follow_answers_on_comment = db.Column(db.Integer)
    send_new_data_notification = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    send_new_members_notification = db.Column(db.Boolean)


    @declared_attr
    def question_event_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_event_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def question_event_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomEventPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_event_preferences.id")

    @declared_attr
    def answer_event_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_event_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def answer_event_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomEventPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_event_preferences.id")

    @declared_attr
    def comment_event_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_event_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def comment_event_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomEventPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_event_preferences.id")

    @declared_attr
    def question_tagging_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_tagging_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def question_tagging_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomTaggingPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_tagging_preferences.id")

    @declared_attr
    def answer_tagging_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_tagging_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def answer_tagging_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomTaggingPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_tagging_preferences.id")

    @declared_attr
    def comment_tagging_preferences_id(cls):
        return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("custom_tagging_preferences.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def comment_tagging_preferences(cls):
        return db.relationship("CustomTaggingPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_tagging_preferences.id")
```

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same or similar issues as described in my question:

I've managed to get my code working by replacing the string variables in the foreign_keys attribute with the column variables itself.

After testing, I found that using a string as foreign_keys attribute always trigged an error for me, but the alternative methods using primaryjoin and foreign_keys=cls.foreign_key worked.

```
@declared_attr
def comment_event_preferences(cls):
    return db.relationship("CustomEventPreferences", foreign_keys="custom_event_preferences.id")
```

becomes:

```
@declared_attr
def comment_event_preferences(cls):
    return db.relationship("CustomEventPreferences", foreign_keys=cls.comment_event_preferences)
```